# Touch event is not working in canvas with fabric.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I am using fabric.js for a uploading image into the canvas but I want to make uploaded image touchable. Means, any user want to use in tablet and the touchable device then it would be work?

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');
document.getElementById('file').addEventListener("change", function (e) {
  var file = e.target.files[0];
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function (f) {
    var data = f.target.result;                    
    fabric.Image.fromURL(data, function (img) {
      var oImg = img.set({left: 0, top: 0, angle: 00,width:100, height:100}).scale(0.9);
      canvas.add(oImg).renderAll();
      var a = canvas.setActiveObject(oImg);
      var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL({format: 'png', quality: 0.8});
    });
  };
  reader.readAsDataURL(file);
});
```

```css
canvas{
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/kangax/fabric.js/master/dist/fabric.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" id="file"><br />
<canvas id="canvas" width="450" height="450"></canvas>
```

I want to make uploaded image touchable. But right now it is work by only cursor.

JSFIDDLE:

https://jsfiddle.net/varunPes/jru2d1pj/1/

If it is possible to make touchable then please let me know. Thanks in advance.

Comment: but its already touchable right?

Comment: @sharma sk. It is not touchable, Please open in tab and developers tools in browser.